# Batch reading a file name

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, windows-7, filenames

Say I have a folder "C:/My Folder" it will have 10 files in it. I need to know how I would set a variable for each file name to an individual variable like:

```
%File1%
%File2%
%File3%
%File4%
%File5%
%File6%
%File7%
%File8%
%File9%
%File10%
```

I have looked on a few sites and I have only found it ether setting the names to one variable or only doing it for one file. Does any one know how I could do it for an individual variable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*"^|findstr /n /r "." ') DO (
 SET "file%%a=%sourcedir%\%%b"   
 )

SET file

GOTO :EOF
```

This should generate and show the list. Your job to set the directory and filemask.

Comment: Sorry I am new to batch what's a file mask.

Comment: The directory is obvious, it's in `sourcedir`. A filemask is a selection mechanism to find only those files whose names match a pattern (called a `filemask`.) So - if you only want the `.csv` files, for instance, you'd use `*.csv` rather than `*` in `"%sourcedir%\*"` (`*` selects all files)

Comment: Thanks I think I can sort something out.